# Web-Role connecting to an IIS endpoint on a Virtual Machine by DNS

Tags: azure, dns, virtual-machine

I have a Web-Role that communicates with an endpoint of a Virtual Machine using the DNS name of the VM:

```
http://<myservice>.cloudapp.net:62002/Endpoint/msmdpump.dll
```

The endpoint is exposed by IIS.

Everything works fine, but since there are a tons of requests made, my question is: Do I loose performance (latency) by using the DNS? Or should I use something like the internal IP address instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS query is *measurable*. Is it enough for you to be concerned about?  Probably not.  But, ultimately that is for you to decide.

The result of the DNS query will be stored in the DNS cache of the client (your WebRole).  So, once the name has been resolved, subsequent calls will be made directly to the IP address (no DNS query) it resolved to, which in this case will be the IP address of the Azure Load Balancer. So, really, the hops are
WebRole > Azure LB > Virtual Machine.

If you do decide to take the path of calling the endpoint using the IP address of the VM then you should setup a [static IP address for the VM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn630228.aspx). Otherwise, you risk having the IP address change on you and therefore breaking your WebRole.  This also requires that your VM be in a Virtual Network.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Don't I also loose performance because the DNS resolves to the load balancer?

Comment: Yes, it will go through the LB first.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I updated my answer.